# What is an easy way to correct the position of the lower jaw of the dog? After animation and parented to armature? Is it possible?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, weight-painting

I have this dog mesh which is already parented to the armature. I made sure that the whole head was parented to the head armature, but the lower jaw still somehow appears to be deformed after animation. Initially it looked fine, but after turning the dog head around, the lower jaw move weirdly. [image]

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Additionally, I tried to edit mesh while it is parented to the armature. It didn't work.

I tried to weight paint the head portion of the mesh again. Which didn't work either.

Update: Since I couldn't figure out how to correct it, I decided to edit each frames that involves the deformed mouth in photoshop. Which kind of sucks, but I think it looks fine, almost noticeable (I think). I would still like to hear the solution though.

Comment: Downloaded your model.  A couple of things, there was no armature modifier on the dog mesh, and there are no actions in the file.  The eyes tongue aren't parented to anything?  maybe the head bone?  There is no root bone of the armature.

Comment: The armature is hidden in the file. Armature modifier not there? Maybe I uploaded the wrong one. I had multiple versions.  As for actions, that is in the other file the big file which have 700MB of info.

Comment: Hmm weird, I couldn't find the right file. So instead I will upload the large file link (zipped) here from dropbox. This will have all the actions and missing informations.

Comment: About the root bone of the armature, I didn't know that was important. I am a novice at blender.  As for the tongue and teeth, I decided to get rid of them.

Comment: Will upload a simple version later. Got to get some sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to do it in a way. I couldn't correct the jaw. What I did was duplicate the lower jaw and then separate it from the body mesh. Reparent the lower jaw (which have to be rescaled and repositioned), but it still follow the animation pretty well.